# Command 'npm run dev' failed NuxtJS

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

I get the following error when I try to run my dev server. I am very new to Vue/Nuxt

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm- 
cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'dev'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.6.3
2 info using node@v15.12.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc 
Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:D:\Projects\TCG\IGG\iggbouwkostenkompas\.npmrc 
Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ghoeksema\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ghoeksema\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc 
Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
19 verbose npm-session 46dffbc867d5c2db
20 timing npm:load Completed in 14ms
21 timing command:run Completed in 694ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
23 verbose pkgid bouwkosten-index@1.0.0
24 verbose cwd D:\Projects\TCG\IGG\iggbouwkostenkompas
25 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
26 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
27 verbose node v15.12.0
28 verbose npm  v7.6.3
29 error code 1
30 error path D:\Projects\TCG\IGG\iggbouwkostenkompas
31 error command failed
32 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c nuxt
33 verbose exit 1
```

I have no idea how fix it and have done some searches but none of the solutions worked for me. Clearing cache also didn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share more details about your project?

Comment: @jonybekov what details will need?